# Add CSS Class by Selector

Tags: css

I hope this isn't a duplicate, but I'm not sure even how to phrase what I'm trying to do. I have some utility CSS rules for like clearing floats and creating horizontal boxes. What I want to do is something like this:

```
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
#someID > div{
    /*apply the .clear class here*/
}
```

I know I can do this with JavaScript, but I would like to avoid having `class="clear"` a million times if I can avoid it. I would also like to avoid duplicating the style information in the second selector so I don't have to maintain multiple utility classes.

The `.clear` class is just an example, my actual classes are more involved.

Comment: may be you have to read this article http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: I've read that article probably a million times. Like I said, this was just a simple example, not the full code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Really, you're just going to have to use your utility classes like `clear` throughout your markup, unless you want to do something like this (which is probably not what you want):

```
.clear, #someID > div 
{
    clear:both;
    /* this assumes you have no other rules here, which probably isn't true */
}
```

In short, there's not much better you can do, unless you want to use a preprocessor for your CSS, like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: +1 for providing LESS link, which let you do the kind of "rule call" the OP wants. (see example with .rounded-corners)

Comment: I'll have to remember LESS. I didn't know about it. It's a little more involved than I want to be right now. I'm not really a UI guy, just fumbling through. Thanks for the answer, even though it was what I was afraid of :)

Comment: No prob, I don't use anything fancy like LESS to make maintaining stylesheets easier, cause I'm usually more concerned about maintenance of my other code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in pure CSS. You can do it easily with [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or jQuery, just use:
`$('#someID > div').addClass('clear');`.

Answer (score -1):

In HTML/CSS, you can have multiple clases like this:

**HTML**

```
<!--If you are using a id and a class:-->
<div id="someID" class="clear"></div>

<!--If you are using 2 classes-->
<div class="someClass clear"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
#someID {
    /* specific style here */
}
.someClass {
    /* specific style here */
}
```